# How to execute UNIX command from Windows XP system using ANT

Tags: windows, unix, shell, ant

I want to execute a UNIX command from my local Windows XP system using ANT script. UNIX system is a remote server.

I have tried the following:

```
  <target name="execute" >
    <sshexec host="host IP" 
    username="uname" 
    password="pass" 
    commandResource="sh abc.sh"/>
  </target>
```

but got the error below:

```
 BUILD FAILED
 ..\build.xml:49: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException:     connection is closed by foreign
 host
```

Comment: Do you get the same message if you try to connect via SSH interactively (e.g. using PuTTY or another SSH client)?

Answer (score 3):

take a look at the [sshexec](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/sshexec.html) ant task.  You will need a [jsch](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/) library on the ant classpath and the UNIX server needs to be running a ssh daemon.

Comment: I already have ant-jsch.jar, jsch-0.1.42.jar at my ANT_HOME/lib. But still got the "JSch Exception: connection is closed by the foreign host"

Comment: Check the /var/log/messages file on the unix server to see what caused the connection to be shutdown.

Comment: I have not found messages at /var/log directories. Checked other files at that location. Not found any SSH related error messages.

Comment: from Windows command prompt where I am running ANT, have received "connection is closed by foreign host" error message.